# While returning HttpResult I cant see customized Headers in the response using C# and ServiceStack

Tags: c#, api, servicestack

I am making a simple API and want to return HTTPResult with some custom headers. I am using Postman to trigger the API but in the Response headers are not displayed.

```
 return new HttpResult($"Ping me, {request.ping}!")
        {
            StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
            ContentType = "text/plain;charset=utf-8",           
            Headers = {
                     ["X-Count-Limit:"] = Counter.ToString(),
                     ["X-Count-Remaining:"] = number.Counter.ToString()
            }
        };
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMUwa.png)

Comment: Is the server sending the headers?  The headers in the response are not the same as what gets sent in the request.

Comment: I made GET method, which I ping from postmen and want to return a simple response to postman with message Ping me, {request.ping}! and StatusCode OK and following custom headers, but I get displayed everything besides the custom headers :(

Comment: You get what the server sends.  The server response is hard coded based on the parameters in the request.  There is no standard filters.  You have to filter the response if you only want part of what the server sends.

Answer (score 1):

Your header names should not contain a ‘:’